# How to use built-in data instead of uploaded data

Tags: r, shiny

I have an app like below. I want to either read-in data from file upload or use the built-in data. I thought I could put an action button and if somebody hit it the input data will mount on and it goes to the next levels. My problem is later in my real app, some widgets such as `selectInput` have to be updated and I want to be empty until user decided whether to use uploaded data or the built-in one.

```
library(shiny)

x <- mtcars 

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput(inputId = "uploadcsv", "", accept = '.csv'),
  actionButton(inputId = "a", label = "action button"),
      selectInput("select",label = h3("Select box"),choices = "",selected = 1)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  data <- reactive({
    infile <- input$uploadcsv

    if (is.null(infile))
      return(NULL)

    read.csv(infile$datapath, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
  })

  DataToUse <- NULL

  observe(!is.null(input$uploadedcsv),
               DataToUse <- data()
  )

  observeEvent(input$a,
               DataToUse <- x
  )

  observe({
    req(DataToUse)
    if (max(DataToUse$cyl) %% 4 == 0){
      numberofinterval <- max(DataToUse$cyl) %/% 4
    } else {
      numberofinterval <- (max(DataToUse$cyl) %/% 4)+1
    }

    NumPeriod <- seq(0, numberofinterval)

    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "select",
                             choices = NumPeriod,
                             selected = NumPeriod)
  })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
library(shiny)

x <- mtcars 

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput(inputId = "uploadcsv", "", accept = '.csv'),
  actionButton(inputId = "a", label = "action button"),
  selectInput("select",label = h3("Select box"),choices = "",selected = 1)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  data <- reactive({
    infile <- input$uploadcsv

    if (is.null(infile))
      return(NULL)

    read.csv(infile$datapath, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
  })

  v <- reactiveValues()
  v$DataToUse <- NULL

  observeEvent(input$uploadcsv,{
    if(!is.null(input$uploadcsv)){
      v$DataToUse <- data()
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$a,v$DataToUse <- x)

  observeEvent(v$DataToUse,{
    req(v$DataToUse)
    if (max(v$DataToUse$cyl) %% 4 == 0){
      numberofinterval <- max(v$DataToUse$cyl) %/% 4
    } else {
      numberofinterval <- (max(v$DataToUse$cyl) %/% 4)+1
    }

    NumPeriod <- seq(0, numberofinterval)

    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "select",
                      choices = NumPeriod,
                      selected = NumPeriod)
  })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you help me with this problem as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49327172/calculation-of-a-function-in-observe-based-on-uploaded-dataset